# How to create a catch all function on a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, plugins

I was previously using the jQuery autosave plugin but have recently removed it. Some code is still trying to use this function, so how can I temporarily extend the jQuery object so there is an empty function to prevent errors until I can get through all of the code that is trying to use the function?

The plugin is called in this way:

```
jQuery().autosave.restore();
jQuery().autosave.save();
```

I think those are the only two functions that exist, so it would be OK to create two empty functions, but is there a way to create a catch-all function on this type of object?

**Note**

This is a temporary solution until I can go through a lot of code. I do believe the question is a valid coding question even if you think this workaround is not ideal (it isn't).

Comment: Clean the code and don't take shortcuts.

Comment: This is a temporary workaround

Comment: What environment are you developing in?  Search/replace on "jQuery().autosave.restore();" and "jQuery().autosave.save();" ?

Comment: The code is serialized in a large mySql database. It has slightly different applications based on what page it is being served up for and I think it would be best to go through it by hand.

Comment: temporary workarounds tend to be there for ever.

Comment: no workarounds tend to lead to broken websites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a way to do this. You can create a dummy plugin (check out jQuery's [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring) for creating plugins):

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.autosave = {
       restore: function() {};
       save: function() {};
  };
})( jQuery );
```

I would highly recommend **against** doing this, however. Instead, you should look at those errors and fix them, i.e., stop your code from using them. Otherwise you're simply hiding the problem.

Comment: This is a temporary workaround until I can go through thousands of lines of non-standard code.

Comment: @cwd, if that's the case then that's alright! Just make sure you *do* fix those errors.

Comment: +1 for giving a good answer and good advice on NEVER DO THIS unless you're back is against the wall!

Answer (score 0):

Nope. Standard JavaScript does not support "catch-all" methods.

Comment: What about __noSuchMethod__ ?
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Object/noSuchMethod

Comment: @Brown: That is not standard JavaScript. It seems to be a Mozilla-specific extension.